# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Request header field password is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I receive the following error message when  doing an ajax request

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Request header field password is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

[image]

I am using the following as header from dojo:

```
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.data.token,
        'X-Requested-With': null,
        'If-None-Match': null,
        'Password': this.data.oneTimePassword
```

Below image of Response Header from Chrome.

I would like to know:

- Could you confirm that the problem is related to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` which does not contain custom header `password`?
- If the endpoint should support only method GET, is `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS` correct in my Response Header, should not be instead only `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET` ?

Currently I am using `dojo/store/JsonRest` but I believe issue is related to API and not to dojo itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is the problem related to Access-Control-Allow-Headers which does not contain custom header password?

Yes. The error message says that explicitly.

> If the endpoint should support only method GET, is Access-Control-Allow-Methods correct in my API?

FSVO correct.

It allows GET so you can make a GET request.

It also allows other methods, which the server would presumably throw a 405 at if the browser tried to make a request using one of them.

Comment: thanks for confirmation. If for that endpoint only GET is possible should the response header return instead `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: Get` instead of `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: Get, POST, PUT, OPTIONS`.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.

Comment: May I ask you? ... What is your opinion in this case? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: I don't have one strong enough to be worth mentioning.